# imagecopyresampled(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource

Tags: php, gd

I am new to facebook app development and working over my first app.
I am trying to resize an image using imagecopyresampled() function but getting this error for it:

> Warning: imagecopyresampled(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in …

```
$url = "http://graph.facebook.com/{$userId}/picture?type=large";
$img = "udp.gif";
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
if (exif_imagetype($img) != IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
    $imgFile = 'temp/' . $userId . '_fdp_' . rand() . '.gif';
    if (exif_imagetype($img) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG)
        $imageObject = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
        if (exif_imagetype($img) == IMAGETYPE_PNG)
            $imageObject = imagecreatefrompng($img);
            $imagegif($imageObject, $imgFile);
            $imgFile1='temp/' . $userId . '_fdp_.gif';
            $imagecopyresampled($imgFile1, $imgFile, 0, 0, 0, 0, 200, 280, 180, 252);
            $img = $imgFile1;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the errror is pretty self explanatory. Where do $img come from?

Comment: Well yes, neither `$imgFile` nor `$imgFile1` (where is that supposed to come from anyway?) are gd resources. Maybe you should read the manual again for examples?

Comment: @DamienPirsy: I just edited my code and hve included the declaration part of $img. hope it'll help.

Comment: @deceze: like am passing the wrong arguments to the function? as per what ive understood from the manual `$imgFile1, $imgFile` are `resource $dst_image , resource $src_image ,`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the argument types. `resource` is a PHP type, like `string` or `float`. Resources need to be created with the appropriate related function. In your case, you need one `resource` of the original image, created with a function like `imagecreatefromjpeg`, and another similar `resource` to copy the image to, most likely a blank image created with `imagecreatetruecolor`.

To quote the [example from the manual](http://www.php.net/imagecopyresampled):

```
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
```

What you have instead is a non-existent variable and a string, which is not the required input.